# Issue trying to query for all "names" on MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm trying to find all "names" in my collection, and I can't figure out how.

I've tried a bunch of different queries, for example -

> db.collectionname.find( { "customers" : {   "id" : 1, "name" : 1 } }

nothing really seems to work.

Here is a relevant part of the collection:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "customers" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "ronald"
    }
}
```

The rest of my collection is essentially identical. I just need to get a list for all the names, for example, ronald in this case. I have no idea how, would appreciate some help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB ? Please update question with the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use aggregations in this case.
What you need is to group customers.name and push each name into an array.

Please refer here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

or if you want unique names only, use addToSet instead of push.

Try this:

> db.collectionname.aggregate([{
>   $group: {
>         _id: null, 
>         names: {
>           $push: "$customers.name"
>         }
>       }
>      }
>     ]).pretty()

This will give you an array "names" with all the names stacked together.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out! I tried it, but got the following error: "2019-01-21T08:05:56.312+0100 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ] after element list @(shell):1:30"

Comment: @EliS. Fixed. Try now?